# "Choose toolbox items" window in visual studio not loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, components, toolbox

In my visual studio (2015), when I open the toolbox window and right click in toolbox and select 'choose items' the choose items window does not show up.

In the status bar it says "Loading choose toolbox items dialog" but the window never loads.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try running `devenv /ResetSettings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this problem too,and i found a solution to fix it.
if you installed "Install shield 2013" just uninstall it and open the VS and try to open "Choose Item dialog".
in my computer its worked.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Install Shield Lite version has some issues with Visual Studio Toolbox. I have removed Install Shield Lite from my PC and now Toolbox is responsive again.
Tested on Win8.1 with VS2017.